# mod_rewrite- matching everything after domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

This rule works fine for http://foo.com/page/contact

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But what I want to do is for http://foo.com/contact

But this is not correct:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

How do I correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your first `/` that's not needed because the root directory is already there. like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

your second example is technically asking for http://foo.com//contact